# Issue pip install igramscraper with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, installation, pip, instagram

I'm trying to install igramscraper on my jupyter notebook in python , but it's not working.

`!pip install igramscraper`

```
Collecting igramscraper
  Downloading igramscraper-0.3.5.tar.gz (24 kB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-fu3_o27u\\igramscraper\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-fu3_o27u\\igramscraper\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-fu3_o27u\igramscraper\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-fu3_o27u\igramscraper\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-fu3_o27u\igramscraper\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        long_description=Path("README.md").read_text(),
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1217, in read_text
        return f.read()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 659: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the file `igramscraper-0.3.5.rar`.
2. unzip the file,find the file `setup.py` in the directory
3. find the line  `long_description=Path("README.md").read_text(),`,and
   comment out this line: `#long_description=Path("README.md").read_text(),`
4. use `python setup.py install` to setup.py the igramscraper,good luck